# Pre-render request cancelled because of timeout

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromium

I am working on adding pre-render optimizations (link rel="prerender" href="...") to my site. I have successfully implemented it on 2 of the pages. The page that I am trying to pre-render now, is not working. Looking in chrome://net-internals/, it shows that the pre-render loaded, but then when I click the link it says in the "Final Status" column, "Timed Out".

The page does not meet any of the cancellation reasons listed in the [pre-render documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/prerender).

Other sources I have found say that it will timeout after 30 or 60 seconds, but this page loads in <5 seconds.

Any ideas? Is there a time limit on pre-render? Is there anyway to change that limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem ended up being that I was 1 character off in my hilariously long url, so the browser was never navigating to the link that I was attempting to pre-render.

I would delete this sad, typo of a question, if it weren't for the fact that I did learn a little bit about chrome://net-internals while going through this.

You will get Final State="Timedout", when the pre-render for a page that IS NOT navigated to is not completed.

You will get Final State="Navigation Uncommitted", when the pre-render for the page that IS navigated to is not completed